# Object with nested attributes - use existing child when child exists in Rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, nested-attributes

I have a flight model that has many passengers in a many_to_many relation. So one passenger can belong to many flights

I have a nested form that creates a flight and some passengers all at once.

```
@ride = Flight.new(flight_params)

def flight_params
  params.permit(:number, :passengers_attributes => [:id, :_destroy, :name, :email, :phone])
end
```

Since it's a many-to-many relationship I have a table that links flights to passengers. Now when I create a new flight with passengers, Rails creates the flight, the passengers and the relationship in the relationship table.

What I want is that if a passenger already exists (identified by its email address) I don't want to create a new passenger but create the relationship between the new flight and the existing passenger (in a next step I might want to update the existing passenger) so that I don't have the same passenger twice in my system.

I have no idea where to start. IS this something I have to do in my model or in my create method?

My passenger model has validation with name as a required field and when I create a new flight the nested attributes are also validated. So I can't simply remove the passengers and create the relations manually because then the validation would fail.

Thanks for any ideas.

Comment: How did you end up doing it?